# What is the best and safest way to run code from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, eval

So this is most likely the wrong way to do this, but I've been giving some thought to this approach for a while and I can't think of a better way to do it.

I am working on a roguelike game with a friend using Javascript and Canvas for the front end and storing our data (monsters, items, etc) into a MySQL database using PHP.

We have divided our playing field into four separate quadrants. The entire play field is a 20 x 20 square and so we have been coding 10 x 10 dungeon quadrants. The idea is to grab code from an array with dungeon quadrant code within it and somehow execute this code. Currently we have four quadrant functions we are calling which draw the environment objects within those quadrants and give them values, but those are hard coded in the functions. I would like to be able to randomly choose a value from the array and place that code inside those functions instead.

I've heard tell of a mysterious and black magic laden procedure called eval(). Do I need to turn to the dark side or is there a better way?

I'll include a little code so you can see the basic idea.

```
////Matrix creation / declaration
var coordinates = new Array(mapWidth);
for (var i = 0; i <mapWidth; i++) {
    coordinates[i] = new Array(mapHeight);          
}

//sets array to 0 which is not an object
for (var i=0; i<mapWidth; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<mapHeight; j++) {
        coordinates[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

function quadrantOneLoader()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 === 1 && i != 3)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 1] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 1].image.src = "images/column.png";
        }
        else if (i % 2 === 1)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 1] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 1].image.src = "images/brokenColumn.png";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 8)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 3] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 3].image.src = "images/column.png";
        }
        else if (i % 2 === 0)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 3] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 3].image.src = "images/brokenColumn.png";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 4)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 7] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 7].image.src = "images/column.png";
        }
        else if (i % 2 === 0)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 7] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 7].image.src = "images/brokenColumn.png";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 === 1 && i !== 7)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 9] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 9].image.src = "images/column.png";
        }
        else if (i % 2 === 1)
        {
            coordinates[x + i][y + 9] = new environment();
            coordinates[x + i][y + 9].image.src = "images/brokenColumn.png";
        }
    }

    coordinates[x + 1][y + 5] = new environment();
    coordinates[x + 1][y + 5].image.src = "images/stocks.png";

    coordinates[x + 4][y + 5] = new environment();
    coordinates[x + 4][y + 5].image.src = "images/candelabra.png";

    coordinates[x + 7][y + 5] = new environment();
    coordinates[x + 7][y + 5].image.src = "images/stocks.png";
}
```

So basically the code that is inside the quadrantOneLoader() function would be placed inside an array. I want to inject that into this function so it would look more like this:

```
function quadrantOneLoader()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    quadrants[Math.floor(Math.random()*quadrants.length())];
}
```

Comment: If you have to use eval you're doing something wrong. Please add some further explanations to your problem (what code is in these functions?) and perhaps even some example code snippets to look at.

Comment: I would not rely on eval() as its something that may not be supported in the future and opens up a whole lot potential problems.  I dont see why you need to execute code like this anyways.  Just pass information about the grid to the page, and have existing javascript functions use it to render the graphic.

Comment: Read some theory about tile map engines, especially how they're saved and loaded. I'm not finding some good tutorials right now, but to start this is probably already useful: http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut01.html There is absolutely no need to use eval!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing something simple like this:

```
var dungeonCode = new Array();

dungeonCode[0] = function(/*pass whatever you want here, we chose to pass x and y*/)
{
    //code to place the dungeon tiles here
}
```

Then to call it all you do is:

```
dungeonCode[0]();
```

We ended up making a bunch of these dungeon quadrants and calling them using a random number generator.

I guess the parenthesis tell the interpreter to execute whatever code contained within the array as a function. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see what you're trying to accomplish with `eval` without seeing some actual code,but a shot in the dark is you could utilize javascript closures to encapsulate the data. You could have an array of functions that return a function that manipulates the data in them and then pass those functions into the function that needs to call on the data;

```
function quadrantBehaviourBuilderOne(someValOne,someValTwo,someValThree){
    var quadrantBehaviour = function(){
        var something = someValueOne - (someValueTwo * someValThree);
        return something;
    }
    return quadrantBehaviour;
}

var behaviourBuilderArray = [quadrantBehaviourBuilderOne,someOtherBuilder,etc];

function somethingThatWorksWithTheBuilder(someBuiltFunction){
       someBuiltFunction();
}

var trees = 5;
var plants = 10;
var locknessmonsters = 350;

var randomNumber = 0;
var myBuiltBehaviourFunction = behaviourBuilderArray[randomNumber](trees,plants,locknessmonsters);
somethingThatWorksWithTheBuilder(myBuiltBehaviourFunction);
```